# How to calculate hourly average per field key and then get max value from those mean values

Tags: sql, influxdb

In my InfluxDB I have field keys such as `InstallationId` and `value` which are stored in a measurement called `measurements`.

I'd like to calculate hourly averages on all records per `InstallationId` from `measurements` that have `value` < 3000 and `type` = `PM25` and were recorded between 1472688000000 ms and 1512000000000 ms and then select max `value` from those hourly averages.

This is a SQL query that I come up with:

```
SELECT max("mean")
FROM
  (SELECT mean("value")
   FROM "measurements"
   WHERE "value" < 3000
     AND "type" = 'PM25'
     AND TIME > 1472688000000ms
     AND TIME < 1512000000000ms
   GROUP BY time(1h))
```

The problem is that this query is calculating mean value from all records per hour and I need it to calculate mean value per hour per `InstallationId`.

I hope I didn't overcomplicated my question. Please let me know if something needs to be clarified.

Answer (score -1):

Then add that to the `group by`:

```
  SELECT instrument_id, time(1h), mean("value")
  FROM "measurements"
  WHERE "value" < 3000 AND "type" = 'PM25' AND
        time > 1472688000000ms AND time < 1512000000000ms
  GROUP BY instrument_id, time(1h)
```

I'm not sure what the `max()` is being used for.  It doesn't seem relevant to your question.  I am also not familiar with the syntax that you are using.  `avg()` is the function normally used in SQL to calculate the average.

Comment: I'm getting: `"error": "error parsing query: mixing aggregate and non-aggregate queries is not supported"`